# argparse option of options

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am trying to add option of options in `argparse`.
Currently I have:

```
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("--md", help="Create xyz file for each ionic step for"
                    " visualization", action='store_true')
group.add_argument("--force", help="See which atom has maximum force",
                    action='store_true')
group.add_argument("--opt", help="grep string from file",
                    nargs=2, metavar=("str", "file"))
parser.add_argument("--xsf", help="Create xsf file for md(default is xyz)"
                    " visualization", action='store_true')
parser.add_argument("-N", help="Showing first N line",
                    metavar='integer', type=int)
parser.add_argument("-n", help="Showing last n line",
                    metavar='integer', type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

which gives:

```
./foo.py --h
usage: foo.py [-h]
               [--md | --force | --opt str file]
               [--xsf] [-N integer] [-n integer]
```

But I want `--xsf` as a suboption for `--md`, `-N,-n` for `--opt`; e.g.

```
./foo.py --h
    usage: foo.py [-h]
                   [--md [--xsf]| --force | --opt str file [-N integer] [-n integer]]
```

But I dont know how to achieve that. May be I am missing something, but there is no option like that in [argparse doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse)

Is there any other way of getting that?

Comment: If I add xsf to group, it can't be used with md, they will be mutually exclusive to one another.

Answer (score 2):

The `mutually_exclusive_group` mechanism is quite simple, and does not work with any kind of nesting, or subgrouping.

There is a Python bug/issue requesting a more comprehensive grouping mechanism, but the proposed patch is rather complicated.  The problem isn't just with testing, it's with defining the groups in a user friendly way, and with generating the `usage` line.  It's nice that you included a desired usage, but that format is well beyond the capabilities of the current help formatter.

You might look into recasting your problem as a subparser one.  subparsers are mutually exclusive (you can only give one command name), and you could specify `--xsf` as an argument for `md`, and `-N` as argument for `--opt`.  But subparsers has its own help issues.

Another route is to write your own `usage`, and do your own testing of arguments after parsing.  With a suitable choice of defaults you can usually tell whether an argument has been provided or not (the user can't specify `None`) or you can ignore unnecessary ones.