# Subparser with parent_parser

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

from the advice by the accepted answer of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016348/argparse-option-of-options), and from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498595/python-argparse-add-argument-to-multiple-subparsers) question, I tried to do:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="output parser")
line_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
line_parser.add_argument("-N", help="Showing first N line",
                    metavar='integer', type=int)
line_parser.add_argument("-n", help="Showing last n line",
                    metavar='integer', type=int)
parser.add_argument("opt", help="grep string from file",
                    nargs=2, metavar=("str", "file"))
subp = parser.add_subparsers()
pscf = subp.add_parser("scf", help="show convergence", parents=[line_parser])#,
pkp = subp.add_parser("kpoint", help="show kpoints")
pnb = subp.add_parser("nband", help="show number of bands")
pmd = subp.add_parser("md", help="Create xyz file for each ionic step for"
                    " visualization")#, action='store_true')
pfrc = subp.add_parser("force", help="See which atom has maximum force")
# parser.add_argument("--xsf", help="Create xsf file for md(default is xyz)"
                    # " visualization", action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

This is giving error:

```
python3 vasp.py --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vasp.py", line 27, in <module>
    args = parser.parse_args()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/argparse.py", line 1728, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/argparse.py", line 1760, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/argparse.py", line 1966, in _parse_known_args
    start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/argparse.py", line 1906, in consume_optional
    take_action(action, args, option_string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/argparse.py", line 1834, in take_action
    action(self, namespace, argument_values, option_string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/argparse.py", line 1016, in __call__
    parser.print_help()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/argparse.py", line 2359, in print_help
    self._print_message(self.format_help(), file)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/argparse.py", line 2336, in format_help
    formatter.add_arguments(action_group._group_actions)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/argparse.py", line 272, in add_arguments
    self.add_argument(action)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/argparse.py", line 257, in add_argument
    invocations = [get_invocation(action)]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/argparse.py", line 535, in _format_action_invocation
    metavar, = self._metavar_formatter(action, default)(1)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

If I remove all of `line_parser`, then it works fine. But I need them, as -N and -n will be used in multiple options, though not shown here.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666197/argparse-combining-parent-parser-subparsers-and-default-values) but haven't managed to assimilate.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is not related to line_parser, but parameter 'metavar' in line 8. Change tuple to list will make your code work.

```
parser.add_argument("opt", help="grep string from file",
                    nargs=2, metavar=["str", "file"])
```

Comment: Changing to a list does let it run.  The help line looks right, but the usage line has `['str', 'file'] ['str', 'file']`, which isn't what BaRud intends.  Something looks buggy.  I'll have to dig into the code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it isn't a `parents` or `subparser` issue, but a `nargs` and `metavar` issue.  There is a relevant Python bug/issue

http://bugs.python.org/issue14074;
`argparse allows nargs>1 for positional arguments but doesn't allow metavar to be a tuple`

I suggested a patch a couple of years ago, but there's a big backlog of argparse issues, so no action has been taken.

---

If `opt` is changed to `--opt`:

```
parser.add_argument("--opt", help="grep string from file",
                nargs=2, metavar=("str", "file"))
```

then the help is:

```
1949:~/mypy$ python stack36095543.py -h
usage: stack36095543.py [-h] [--opt str file] {scf,kpoint,nband,md,force} ...

output parser

positional arguments:
  {scf,kpoint,nband,md,force}
    scf                 show convergence
  ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --opt str file        grep string from file
```

I think that's what is intended.

Changing the metavar to a list produces

```
usage: stack36095543.py [-h] [--opt ['str', 'file'] ['str', 'file']]
                    {scf,kpoint,nband,md,force} ...
```

which I don't think is the intended usage.

According to the docs:

> Providing a tuple to metavar specifies a different display for each of the arguments:

I would suggest going with the `--opt` argument.  One, it gets this metavar display right.  Two, `positionals` don't play that nicely with subparsers.  A subparser is a positional argument as well (in disguise).  I think it is safer to define the other main parser arguments as 'optionals'

Note, if I make `--opt` `required=True`, the usage like is:

```
usage: stack36095543.py [-h] --opt str file {scf,kpoint,nband,md,force} ...
```

In that case it's a bit hard to distinguish between flag and argument.  `argparse` uses upper case for the default `optionals` metavars.  It is clear if get use:

```
 usage: stack36095543.py [-h] --opt STR FILE {scf,kpoint,nband,md,force} ...
```

Another possibility is to replace the `nargs=2` argument with 2 positionals

```
parser.add_argument("grep",metavar='STR')
parser.add_argument("file",metavar='FILE')
```

producing:

```
usage: stack36095543.py [-h] STR FILE {scf,kpoint,nband,md,force} ...
```

A `positional` with `nargs=2` (or *,+) is best reserved for cases where all values are the same kind of thing - values in a list.  Where they represent different things, it makes more sense to use separate arguments.

---

On further testing I find that your code handles the usage just fine.  `parser.print_usage()` produces:

```
usage: stack36095543.py [-h] str file {scf,kpoint,nband,md,force} ...
```

the error is produced when formatting the help line.  A line that should look like:

```
str file        grep string from file
```

And according to my posts on the bug/issue, a metavar like this also has problems when displaying an error message.